# Sorting group columns in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

I am grouping (and aggregating) on a column.  Using the example on the ag-grid site, let's say it's Country.   I am using these options:

```
groupUseEntireRow: true,
groupHideGroupColumns: true
```

and when I define the Country column in the columnDefs I add:  rowGroupIndex: 0

But when the grid loads, the Country groupings do not show in alphabetical order by default. How can I get them to sort?  I didn't see anything in the documentation that explains this.

Note that I do NOT need to allow the user to sort Country later, I just want to order by Country when the grid loads.

Comment: You can disable the sorting with suppressSorting and yet use the sort attribute to fix the sort of the column.

Note : group sorting just came out with 3.3.0 from 08th February 2016

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-column-definitions/index.php

Comment: Thanks.  I saw the code at the bottom of the page and that fixed it!

Comment: @Walfrat put it as an answer so it can get accepted, it's kinda tricky that the answer is here in comments ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting my comment as an answer so the author can accept it :

You can disable the sorting with suppressSorting and yet use the sort attribute to fix the sort of the column.

Note : group sorting just came out with 3.3.0 from 08th February 2016 ag-grid.com/angular-grid-column-definitions/index.php

Comment: For anyone wondering how to get the grid to sort properly by default if you DO want the the user to be able to sort the items; you need to rely on the fact that agGrid's unsorted order is the order the data is passed into the grid. Because row groups are not passed into the grid, you just need to be clever with how you order your "leaf" data to get the groups to appear properly!